# Computing the derivative of the CDF of a gamma random variable

Tags: probability, derivatives, gamma-distribution

In class, my professor computed the density of a gamma random variable by taking the derivative of its CDF, but he skipped many steps. I am trying to go through the derivation carefully but cannot reproduce his final result.

Let $k$ be the shape and $\mu$ be the scale. Then the CDF for a gamma random variable $T$ is

$$
F(t) = 1 - \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{e^{-\mu t} (\mu t)^{i}}{i!}
$$

Using the product rule, I get

$$
\begin{align}
f(t)
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial t} F(t)
\\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Big( 1 - \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{e^{-\mu t} (\mu t)^{i}}{i!} \Big)
\\
&= - \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Big( \frac{e^{-\mu t} (\mu t)^{i}}{i!} \Big)
\\
&= - \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{1}{i!} \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Big( e^{-\mu t} (\mu t)^{i} \Big)
\end{align}
$$

where

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Big( e^{-\mu t} (\mu t)^{i} \Big) = e^{-\mu t} (-\mu)(\mu t)^i + e^{-\mu t} i (\mu t)^{i-1}
$$

Putting everything together, we get

$$
f(t)
=
\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{\mu e^{-\mu t} (\mu t)^i}{i!}
-
\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{e^{-\mu t} (\mu t)^{i-1}}{(i-1)!}
$$

But here I am stuck. I know that

$$
f(t) = \frac{\mu e^{-\mu t} (\mu t)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}
$$

but am not sure how to get there.

Comment: You have some omissions in your product and chain rules line:  $$  \frac{\partial}{\partial t} (\dots)= \mathrm{e}^{- \mu t} (-\mu) (\mu \underline{t})^i + \mathrm{e}^{-\mu t} \underline{i} \mu (\mu t)^{i-1}  \text{.}  $$

Comment: Thanks. The first one was a typo but the second was a mistake and critical for factoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) note that the second sum starts from $i=1$;
that's because when you derivate $\frac{(\mu t)^i}{i!}$ you get
$\frac{i(\mu t)^{i-1}}{i!}$ which is $0$ for $i=0$, and only for $1 \le i$ becomes $\frac{(\mu t)^{i-1}}{(i-1)!}$
b) factor out $e^{-\mu t}$
c) you are left with a telescoping sum

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Just to clarify, I factored out $\mu e^{- \mu t}$. If a term in a series is undefined, is it mathematically acceptable to just remove that term by updating the index (your first point above).

Comment: Glad it helped. But concerning the index of second sum, **no**, $0$ is not removed because $(i-1)!$ is otherwise not defined (which is not allowed, and just indicates there is a fault somewhere), it is the result of the derivation : I added a note in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to manually check what's going on with the first one or two terms in the sum for $F$ as you take the derivative, since introducing "$(-1)!$" is not happening.  (That is, you have divided by zero in your shown work.)